# Add dimensions like in technical drawings

Tags: dimensions

How can I add dimensions of objects like in technical drawings like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use an addon called MeasureIt

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OoMwmUrOhdc

[image]

It comes with Blender and you will find it in addons

[image]